# Why is lock_guard a template?

Tags: c++, concurrency, mutex

I just learned about [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) and I was wondering why it is a template.
Until now I have only seen `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` with `std::mutex` inside the angle brackets.

Comment: You could implement and use your own mutex if needed.

Comment: Also note that since C++17 you do not need specify template parameter explicitly, since template deduction guide specified for `std::lock_guard` will handle this.

Comment: So you can re-use the class with any class that has `lock()` and `unlock()` methods. Code re-use is a useful feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` is indeed quite common.
But you can use `std::lock_guard` with **other mutex types:**

1. Various standard mutex types, e.g.: [`std::recursive_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex).
2. Your own mutex type. You can use any type, as long as it is a [`BasicLockable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BasicLockable), i.e. it supports the required methods: `lock()`, `unlock()`.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my questions and I will look into how to define my own mutex. I will accept the answer ASAP

Comment: @roi_saumon -- This is basically *compile-time polymorphism*, where the template calls function <x>, which is provided by the template type (in this case, `lock()` and `unlock()`).  It is a technique used widely, not just in `std::lock_guard`.